# Could not find table 'types' during Type.new call in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sqlite

I am having a problem where RSpec is crashing out when I endeavour to run a model test on the app I have recently inherited.

My test database is configured like this:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
```

The Schema looks like this:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "event"
    t.boolean "deleted", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

My "Category" class looks like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     # couple of method calls but no attributes.
   end
```

The Spec file begins like this:

```
 describe "Category Model" do
   let(:category) { Category.new }
   # doesn't matter, crashes after this line.
```

The outcome is:

```
 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:512:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'categories' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Every other question on this topic I can find seems to suggest that there is a problem with the rake db preparation, but this happens regardless of whether I run `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:test:load` ahead of time.

Is there any way to check what is in that database? Should I be forcing it to create a file instead, so I can see what that looks like? Am I missing something else obvious that could be causing this problem?

Edited to add: Also, given that `db:test:prepare` is deprecated, what is the "Rails 4" way of preparing the test database?

Comment: Hmmm... starting to look like maybe the memory database was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since your database is in memory, you need to recreate it every time. See this [blog post](http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2006-02-08-in-memory-sqlite-database-for-rails-testing)

> Add the following code right below the “# Include your application
>   configuration below” line in environment.rb.
>
> ```
> def in_memory_database?
>   ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "test" and 
>   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class == ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteAdapter and
>   Rails::Configuration.new.database_configuration['test']['database'] == ':memory:'
> end
>
> if in_memory_database?
>   puts "creating sqlite in memory database"
>   load "#{RAILS_ROOT}/db/schema.rb" # use db agnostic schema by default
>   # ActiveRecord::Migrator.up('db/migrate') # use migrations
> end
> ```
>
> The reason for adding this code at this point and not just at the end
>   of the environment file is that you may have further logic in
>   environment that actually relies on the database being present.